# What makes a rails param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord, strong-parameters

I've built a couple rails sites so far (really enjoyable framework to use) but I'm gradually noticing that my monkey-see-monkey-do method of learning strong params has apparently left a gap or two in my understanding.

Looking below at a simple example (the [Recipe Box by mackenziechild](https://github.com/mackenziechild/recipe_box))

```
def recipe_params
        params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description, :image, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], directions_attributes: [:id, :step, :_destroy])
end
```

I don't actually know why he's able to reference `:recipe` as a parameter.  My loose understanding of parameters is that they're essentially columns in a table however the above example would imply that they can also be the name of the table itself.  (No column is named "recipe", though one of the tables is named "recipes").

Would I be correct in then understanding that when I generate a model `MyThing` (singular CamelCase) and therefore a corresponding table, `my_things` (plural snake_case), I automatically have a corresponding parameter `:my_thing` (singular snake_case with a colon) at my disposal?

My questions are as follows:

1. Is the above understanding accurate?
2. Are there any other parameters that correspond to something other than table names and column names?  If so what are they?
3. Is there a way to list the parameters that I have at my disposal (something similar to `rake routes`)?

Many thanks in advance for any clarification offered!

Comment: Parameters are just that: parameters. It's a hash. For a recipe they come in under the hash key `:recipe`. It's not the name of a table, or a column, it's just a hash key. So are all the rest. If you want to be able to pass in a parameter it must be permitted--they can be named arbitrarily, e.g., you could pass in a hidden field that isn't a part of any table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` available in your controller are merely the result of the names of the fields in the form in the browser. The names of the fields in the form follow a convention that Rails has created using the form helper functions that you are using in your views.

When you have this in a view:

```
= form_for @recipe do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
```

Then that will generate the following HTML:

```
<form stuff-here>
  <input name="recipe[title]" other-stuff>
```

And that `name` attribute in HTML will result in the value of that field being exposed in your controller as `params[:recipe][:title]`  **That's** where params come from, and if you changed any parts of that then the names of the `params` would be different.

So to your questions:

1. Sort of, you arrived at the right conclusion, but perhaps didn't know why :)
2. You can have any `params` you like, depending on the form helpers you use, and how you use them. Everything can be overridden.
3. You can always do: `logger.debug params.inspect` in your controller and that will allow you to see (in your `log/development.log` file) what `params` are there for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `params` hash is basically the data sent by the browser (or API client). They're not defined anywhere because a browser can send anything it wants to you (try adding &foo=bar to the end of a URL in your app and see how this adds an entry to params), although in general your application probably expects the data to be in a certain shape.

On their own parameters don't mean much; what matters is how they are used. If you are passing them to `SomeModel.create` then the keys should be names of attributes in your model (and you should use strong parameters to control what attributes can be set). That is only one (albeit frequent) use of them: they might contains criteria for a search for example.